# woocommerce coupons restrict one coupon per product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I have setup a 'Fixed Product Discount' coupon under woocommerce plugin in wordpress. I want to restrict one coupon per product quantity. How can I do this?

For example, there is a product X. I have created a coupon and selected the product i.e product X to which this coupon should apply(from the Usage Restriction tab).

Now there is a possibility that a user can have multiple coupons. But I do not want the user to apply multiple coupons for one quantity of the product. If the user selects 2 quantities of product X, then he/she should be able to apply 2 coupons. But if the user selects only one quantity of product X, then he/she should be able to apply only one coupon.

How can I achieve this?

The options which is there under Usage limits do no fulfil this requirement.

Comment: [Search for plugins](https://www.google.com/search?&q=woocmmerce+coupon+plugin) … If you don't find anything convenient and if you don't have the knowledge, you will have to hire a skilled developer.